# Jquery Change background image of body on hover

Tags: jquery

I've been trying to change the background image of the body on hover.
So far I've tried using:

```
    $('#bob')
    .hover(function(){
        $('body').css("background", "url('" + images[0] + "'");
    })
```

Which doesn't work for me atleast.
I can't seem to figure it out
Here is my array "images" if that is necessary.

```
    var images = ['x/bg/bob.jpg', 'x/bg/sotd.jpg', 'x/bg/wws.jpg', 'x/bg/dk.jpg', 'x/bg/tp.jpg'];
```

Comment: It just wouldn't work is all but the answer Fabrizio gave worked for me atleast in chrome, it doesn't seem to work properly in Firefox. Scratch that, it works in FF and Chrome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('body').css("background", "url(" + images[0] + ")");
```

a `)` is missing.
(Single quotes are not necessary)

Comment: Thanks for the incredibly quick answer! Obviously it worked like a charm.